# Foldername as parameter

Tags: bash

As part of a txt file with instructions on how to run, I use a folder name as a parameter as shown below. However, LINUX does not recognize it. What could I be doing wrong?

```
foldername = "SOPHIE_TRANS"
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "CellSort($foldername);quit"
```

Comment: add `set -x` before your `matlab` command to make sure your script or command is doing what you thing it's doing.

Comment: The code contains a typo (spaces around `=`).

Answer (score 3):

You are not setting a valid variable.  You cannot have a space between the variable name, the equals, nor the variable value.

Try like this:

```
foldername="SOPHIE_TRANS"
matlab -nodesktop -nosplash -r "CellSort($foldername);quit"
```